# localhost double hop security negotiation timeout (IIS Integrated mode only)

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have a set of websites making calls between each other (all on localhost on the same box).

Site A makes a series of parallel asynchronous calls to an ASMX webservice on site B.

Service on site B makes a call to a WCF service on site C (which uses windows authentication).

This all works fine on my development machine when site C is running in an app pool using 'classic' mode for .net 4.0. (Site A is using integrated mode).

When we change to using integrated mode for site B, I start to get timeouts in the security negotiation between site B and site C.  This happens only for some of the set of parallel requests sent from site A.

Exception shown is: "Client is unable to finish the security negotiation within the configured timeout "

Not all of the requests will timeout, but seems to be the majority will.

Irritatingly, while this doesn't work on my local machine (Windows 7), it does seem to work on our testing server (Server 2008 R2).

If anybody has any pointers?

---

Just a quick note - this seemed to be an issue when both sites were within the same application pool on my development machine.  Changing this has sorted it out, but I still don't entirely understand why this was happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue when both sites were within the same application pool on my development machine. Changing this has sorted it out, but I still don't entirely understand why this was happening.